# If you get a chance, could you please help me improve my HTML and CSS codes for border style dash with black background?

Tags: html, css

I was able to achieve the overall design but I am a bit worried about the way I code because I am aware that I am not using the best practice.

These are my codes:

````
     
    #formatting {
     text-align: center;
     padding: 25px;
     padding-top:10px;
     padding-bottom:10px;
     display:inline-block;
     color:#ffffff;
        }
   .thindash {
     background: #000000;
     border: 2px dashed #ffffff;  
     position: relative;
     }

   .thindash:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: -1px;
    top: -1px;
    right: -1px;
    bottom: -1px;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    pointer-events: none;
}
    
    </style>
    <div style="background: #000000; padding: 15px; display: inline-block;">
    
    <div class='thindash' id="formatting">
      <h3>Working Hours</h3>
        <p>Monday to Friday</p>
        <p>8 AM - 12 PM (Lunch - Dinner)</p>
        <p>8 AM - 11 AM (Morning Breakfast)</p>
    </div>
    </div>```
````

Comment: This site is intended to solve problems, not to do the work for you.

Comment: No worries, Ali.

Comment: Now your question looks better

Answer (score 2):

You are unlikely to get someone to clean your code. However I can provide a couple of tips regarding the code above.

1. Don't use inline styles on your outer `<div>`. Use a class instead.
2. Unless you have a specific reason to do so which is not obvious from the code above, do not use an `id` for styling `#formatting`. Either use the `thindash` class you already have or make `formatting` a class rather than an id.
3. You don't need to use `padding`, `padding-top` and `padding-bottom` on `#formatting`. `padding` is shorthand for `padding-top padding-right padding-bottom padding-left`. Presumably you want 25px padding on the left and the right and 10px bottom and top. As such you can just write `padding: 10px 25px`. That will give you 10px top and bottom and 25px left and right. [More information on padding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding).

Don't get too frustrated; read articles and tutorials (there's tonnes of free resources online); and keep practising.